# Different Single as homepage for other languages

Tags: localization, singles

How can I give another localization its own "Single" as homepage. My main language has its own very unique homepage but for the other languages I need all the fields and HTML/CSS of my about us page. I want to do this without adding all the fields to some other tab in my homepage.

Is there any possible way to make this happen. I tried already to set the homepage for the main language open. Created a new Single for the other language but I dont have the option to set it as homepage for the current language.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use the "This is for the homepage" checkbox at all. All it does is to (1) set up
a route to the entry template specified in the section settings and (2) make the entry model available to this template
from an `entry` variable.

You can just deselect this option and configure the above manually. The simplest way to set up a route for the homepage is
to create a template index.html in craft/templates/ and Craft picks it up automatically for hompage requests (→ see pt. 6 in the [routing docs](https://craftcms.com/docs/routing)).

You can now query for the entry model (your "single") depending on the requested locale to solve (2) and then include a template partial
into the index.html to solve (1).

```
{% if craft.locale == 'fr' %}
    {% set entry = craft.entries.section('home_fr').first() %}
    {% include '_pages/home_fr' %}
{% elseif craft.locale == 'de' %}
    {% set entry = craft.entries.section('home_de').first() %}
    {% include '_pages/home_de' %}
{% else %}
    {% set entry = craft.entries.section('home').first() %}
    {% include '_pages/home' %}
{% endif %}
```